# How to install new font in TeXmacs and refresh font cache in OS X?

Tags: fonts, texmacs

In order to install font Fandol, I've put font files into ~/.TeXmacs/fonts/truetype. But when I want to refresh TeXmacs font cache with shell command "texmacs --delete-font-cache", the shell shows "Unknown command 'texmacs'". I install TeXmacs by .dmg file. So how could I refresh font cache of TeXmacs? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know exactly where you install texmacs in, then run:

> $ path/to/the/binary --delete-font-cache

Comment: Thanks! The path is /Applications/TeXmacs.app/Contents/MacOS/TeXmacs in my Mac.

Comment: @Definiter For GNU TeXmacs v1.99.19, use Tools -> Font -> Clear font cache and restart GNU TeXmacs